# 7 band EQ frequencies for full-track playback?

Tags: equalization, frequency, theory, frequency-response

I used to have a Mackie analog mixer, but I've switched over to using a midi controller (Launch Control XL), and I'm not limited by the 5 bands that existed on the Mackie (low cut, 80, 250, 800, 2500, 8000).

I'm using the EQ for playback, so that I can "play" the notes as they come; rumble, punch, mud, piano/harp chords, claps, and rides etc.

I ported these frequencies over because I thought they might've designed to hit different keys equally. In Ableton, I turned all knobs and changed the Q so that I got a relatively flat line between peaks.

I'm curious if anyone has suggestions for a 7 band EQ. Maybe 7 bands is too much, and I should focus on other audio transformations. Ultimately, I'd like to DJ and mix streams efficiently.

Comment: You're using an EQ for playback, so you can play notes? What does that mean exactly? Why don't you just EQ each sound beforehand and just play the sample?

Comment: @AytAyt I use EQ on full tracks from my collection, I don't have the stems

Comment: Ah, so you would have the EQ settings change dynamically, or at a trigger that you press, to go best with each type of note that comes up? Very interesting.